# How to convert decimal seconds to time with fractional seconds in PHP

Tags: php, time

I am trying to solve an issue where I need to be able to convert a time in seconds with decimal places such as `375.844` I need to convert it to the following format:
`HH:MM:SS.0` rather than rounding to the nearest whole second
I believe the number above should display as `00:06:15.8`

This is part of a wider program where the user enter hours, minutes and seconds allowing tenths of a second.

I convert this all into seconds using the following function:

```
public function timetosecs() {
    return $this->hours * (60 * 60) + $this->mins * 60 + $this->secs * 1;
}
```

It then performs some calculations on the seconds to adjust them, multiplying by a factor of `0.866` and then this is the function to convert them back to time format however it does not seem to display the tenths.

```
  public function secstotime($totalSeconds) {
    $hours = floor($totalSeconds / 3600);
    $totalSeconds %= 3600;
    $minutes = floor($totalSeconds / 60);
    $seconds = floor(($totalSeconds % 60) * 10) / 10;
    return $hours . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sprintf()` function to set leading digits:

```
function secstotime($totalSeconds) {
    $startTotalSeconds = $totalSeconds;
    $hours = floor($totalSeconds / 3600);
    $totalSeconds %= 3600;
    $minutes = floor($totalSeconds / 60);
    $seconds = $startTotalSeconds - ($minutes * 60);
    return sprintf("%02d",$hours) . ":" . sprintf("%02d",$minutes) . ":" .sprintf("%.1f", $seconds);
}


//...
echo secstotime(375.844); // prints 00:06:15.8
```